# Member reports javascript broken after update

Tags: civireport, javascript, 5.33.0

Somewhere between 5.15 and 5.36, javascript starts breaking on all member reports.

In the html body, javascript is searching for

```
$originalElement = $dateElement.siblings('#membership_join_date_from').hide(),
        date_format = $originalElement.attr('format'),
```

and later does

```
date_format.indexOf('m') > -1
```

In my source, `membership_join_date_from` is not a sibling of $dateElement. it is nested inside a sibling `span.crm-form-date-wrapper` (and it doesnt have an attribute called `format`).

So `date_format` is undefined and the error stops javascript execution; the form layout with tabs and such breaks, even showing the SQL output when generating results.

Since nobody seems to have this, I am wondering if it is something with my reports ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, my bad. I had to update the `nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport` extension, too.